# Dotnet Core 2.2 Authentication Builder: AddMicrosoftAccount vs AddAzureAD

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-account

What is the difference between AddMicrosoftAccount and AddAzureAD in the Authentication Builder in DotNet Core 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

AddMicrosoftAccount adds the authentication scheme for personal Microsoft accounts, aka Live accounts / Hotmail accounts / Outlook accounts.

AddAzureAD adds the authentication scheme for organizational Azure Active Directory login.
Users can then login using their Office 365/Azure AD account.